# Al utilizar mysql de xampp junto con Nginx ocurren errores

Tags: mysql, xampp, nginx

apenas empecé a probar nginx y sé lo básico. Y noté que podía utilizar el servidor Mysql de xampp y ahorrarme un buen tiempo, pero noté que al utilizarlo, configurarlo y etc, si apagas el mysql en xampp y intentas volverlo a iniciar muestra que el puerto 3306 está ocupado sin haber ningún programa que lo utilice.

¿Algunas recomendaciones de cómo configurar Mysql en nginx, o que no debí hacer? Gracias :)

Comment: Cambia el puerto de MySQL o mira que procesos estan corriendo en ese puerto con `netstat -aon`

Comment: Ok, pero es correcto usar el servidor Mysql de xampp como alternativa?, es decir, para no hacer todo manualmente y instalar php,mysql en nginx.

Comment: Nginx no requiere de MySQL, el problema que muy seguramente tienes es que instalaste MySQL o MariaDb en solitario además del de Xampp y por eso el puerto TCP 3306 está ocupado por uno e impide el inicio del otro. Si quieres instalar y usar Nginx desde un paquete LAMP, en vez de usar XAMPP puedes probar algo como WTNMP (https://winnmp.wtriple.com/).